# Python setting range of monotonic values in array to zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an array of monotonically increasing values, how do I set the end values to zero? For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2,2.2,3.1,4.4,8.3,9])
b = 4.5

for i in np.arange(b,max(a)):
    np.put(a,[i],[0])

print(a)
```

Comment: What is the expected output that you want?  Do you want to set everything up to 4.5 to 0? Or everything after? Or something else?

Comment: I want to get rid of 8.3 and 9 so that the output is an array containing `1.2,2.2,3.1,4.4,0,0`. And I've also fixed a dumb mistake in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's worth the effort to take advantage of the fact that if it's monotonically increasing you can save yourself many comparisons.  Simply write

```
>>> a = np.array([1.2,2.2,3.1,4.4,8.3,9])
>>> a[a > 4.5] = 0.0
>>> a
array([ 1.2,  2.2,  3.1,  4.4,  0. ,  0. ])
```

and get on with your day.  I suppose you could experiment with something like

```
>>> a = np.array([1.2,2.2,3.1,4.4, 8.3, 9])
>>> a[np.searchsorted(a, 4.5):] = 0
>>> a
array([ 1.2,  2.2,  3.1,  4.4,  0. ,  0. ])
```

but you'd have to think through how you want to handle the edge case.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a list, something like the following should work

```
a = [1.2,2.2,3.1,4.4,8.3,9]
b = 4.5
a = map(lambda x: x if x <=b else 0.0, a)
```

If you want to work with numpy objects

```
a = np.array([1.2,2.2,3.1,4.4,8.3,9])
b = 4.5
a = np.array(map(lambda x: x if x ><=b else 0.0, a.tolist()))
```

EDIT: this is not the most computationally efficient way to compute this operation, but it should be effective.

Comment: Yes, but it should have `x<=b` instead.